# An element in a ring that is both a unit and a zero-divisor - can you find my mistake?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I'm getting a contradiction with mathematics. Can you find my mistake?

So, let $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$. Then $\mathfrak{p}=(x-1,y)$ is a prime ideal in $A$, because it's a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $(xy)$. Let $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the localization at $\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e. we invert all the elements that aren't in $\mathfrak{p}$).

Then, $x$ is a unit in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, because it wasn't in the ideal. But also $xy=0$, so $x$ is also a zero-divisor. This is absurd.

I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see what.

Comment: Since $A$ is not an integral domain, your description of "the localization at $\mathfrak{p}$" is not apt.  Check your references about how a localization is defined if there are zero divisors.

Comment: what you have discovered is that localization at a prime ideal is not necessarily injective! for a perhaps more mundane example, consider the localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\big/6\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $2\mathbb{Z}\big/6\mathbb{Z}$. this is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}\big/3\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction since $y=0$ in $A_{\mathfrak p}$. In fact, it is better to write $\frac y1=\frac 01$, and this holds since there is an element in $A\setminus\mathfrak p$ which annihilates $y$ (guess which one?).

Comment: As a matter of fact $A_{\mathfrak p}\simeq\mathbb C[x]_{(x-1)}$ which is an integral domain.